# I am the owner of azure subscription but not part of azure ad, how?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have subscribed to *Azure* free trial using company mail id and I am the owner of the *Azure* subscription. But I am not able to view/access *Azure AD* why?

If I don't have permissions how the solution is deployed? I have deployed azure accelerators by following below URL:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-accelerators/quickstart-remote-monitoring-deploy

I am not able access my Azure app services deployed applications why?

Comment: Please add more details

Answer (score 0):

When you go to the following URL, what error you are seeing?
https://aad.portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/ActiveDirectoryMenuBlade

Something like this?

> You don't have permission to read/create/delete Azure Active Directory (AAD) applications. Please contact your AAD administrator and have them either enable app registrations in 'user settings' of AAD or assign your account one of the following roles: 'Application Developer', 'Cloud Application Administrator', 'Application Administrator', or 'Global Administrator'.

If so, I would say: Try to create a User - RBAC - Application Administrator
and deploy the solution accelerator using the newly created user.

Still having issues? Email the Microsoft SDS team at sds-support@microsoft.com.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, Thanks for your reply. I am the subscription owner but not able to access AD as Ii am getting error says simply "No access" and ad id--

Comment: Dropped mail to ms-support team as you suggested

Comment: Question here is why I am not able to access AAD even though I am the account admin and owner of subscription